# Syn 5e to dnd-5e?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/5e/info) tag again, that's distinct from [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e).  Should we synonymize it or just wait for it to be cleaned up again? (pretty sure I've removed this tag to let it die before...)

Comment: Closing this as a dupe of the request where this issue was finalised.

Answer (score 7):

It's definitely not the first time that tag's come up, and I've removed it once or twice myself.

I'll get it added to our tag blacklist. Specifically, we'll blacklist a tag that's composed just of number followed by an "e" (or "ed" or "edition").

I'm not inclined to synonymise it: other 5th editions exist, and since this isn't D&D Stack Exchange, our tags shouldn't be synonymised like that. If we instead blacklist it we can use this as a learning opportunity about our taxonomy, since blacklisted tags can come with information about what to do instead.

---

The blacklist request has been raised here: [Blacklist #-edition tags](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8290/blacklist-edition-tags)