# Blacklist bare [#-edition] tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

D&D editions sometimes colloquially go by their edition number alone, and people sometimes enter just the edition for a tag. We've had to burninate the [5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5e) tag a few times.

I'd like the following regex pattern to get blacklisted in tags:

```
^\d-?(e|ed|edition)$
```

This ought to blacklist any tag that's simply a digit followed by `e`, `ed`, or `edition`, optionally separated by a dash. (And not blacklist [dnd-5e] or similarly formed tags.)

I recommend the following for the blacklisted tag popup message:

> Our site caters to hundreds of tabletop RPGs. Say which game you're playing, not just its edition, e.g.: [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), [7th-sea-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7th-sea-2e), [shadowrun-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun-5e), [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e)

```
Our site caters to hundreds of tabletop RPGs. Say which game you're playing, not just its edition, e.g.: [tag:dnd-5e], [tag:7th-sea-2e], [tag:shadowrun-5e], [tag:gurps-4e]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Went with `^\d+(st|nd|rd|th)?-?(e|ed|edition)$` just to discourage obvious work-arounds:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, those workarounds are a good idea.